# Cron job issue Magento 2

Tags: cron, magento2

trying to run custom cron in magento 2 giving below error in system.log file

**main.WARNING: Could not acquire lock for cron group: default, skipping run [] []**

Comment: Please add your code here.

Comment: @khasru please check here for details

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/304483/magento-2-custom-cron-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code for custom cron

Create crontab.xml in app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/ folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
     <group id="default">
       <job name="bestseller_cronjob" instance="Test\Customcron\Cron\Bestseller" method="execute">
         <schedule>0 1 * * *</schedule>
       </job>
     </group>
   </config>
```

And create on instance file for cron execute
app/code/Test/Customcron/Cron/Bestseller.php

```
<?php
  namespace CP\Coreoverride\Cron;
  use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
  class Bestseller {
    public function execute() 
    {
       //your code goes here
    }
  }
```

You can execute cron by below command

> php bin/magento cron:run (for all cron execute)
>     php bin/magento cron:run --group="bestseller_cronjob" (particular cron group)

Comment: Yes i did the same https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/304483/magento-2-custom-cron-not-working